# Explode a layer into multiple layers based on an attribute field, using QGIS

Tags: qgis, layers, select-by-attribute, split-by-attribute

I have a layer where every feature contains a `type` attribute with a value from a restricted set. Is there a way in QGIS to explode the layer into multiple layers, one for each value for the `type` attribute?

Answer (score 5):

In QGIS, there is a specific algorithm that does exactly what you need. It is the "split vector by attribute".
You can find details [here](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeneral.html#split-vector-layer).